# Need help in parsing arguments in awk

Tags: awk

My input file looks like this:

> chr1  150979866   150980273   NM_001303242    chr1    150979273   150980273   NM_001163260    1000

and I want to separate the file based on minimum and maximum values in the 
9th column. Where min= 0-500 and max=>500-1000.

I wrote an awk script `awk -v min=0 -v max=500 ' $9==0 { next } min <= $9 && $9 <= max { print }'` .

But the script does not work.

Can someone help.
Thanks.

Comment: Show a sample with 5 to 10 lines of input with your expected output. Also, when you say "does not work", does not work how? No output? Wrong output? Syntax error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below line generate two o/p files : **min**(0-500) and **max**(501-1000)

```
awk '$9 >= 0 && $9 <= 500 {print $0>"min"} $9 > 500 && $9 <= 1000 {print $0>"max"}' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v min=500 -v max=1000 '   $9 == 1000 { next }   min <= $9 && $9 <= max { print }' file
```

awk -v min=0 -v max=500 '   $9 == 500 { next }   min <= $9 && $9 <= max { print }' file
It worked.
Thanks everyone for their inputs.